# How to get the result of a scheduled job in play-framework?

Tags: java, playframework, scheduled-tasks, playframework-1.x

I have a job scheduled which runs every few minutes, But how do I get the result of this job when it is finished ?

The job gets data from the database and returns the result.

Since only `Job.in()` and `Job.now()` return a `promise` result , How do I get it from a Scheduled job that runs every few minutes .

I am using `playframework 1.2.5Rc1`

Comment: Is there a reason why you cannot just add your logic to the job that queries the database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to store the result somewhere else. Then you can look up the results when you need them. It doesn't really make sense to "return" a result from a scheduled job because you never really have a reference to them. The API could return a promise for the first scheduled job, but that would leave all the other scheduled jobs in the dark.

One thing you could do is have the scheduled job push results into a [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html). Then elsewhere in your code you can call the `take()` method which blocks until it can pull something out of the queue. This would kind of act like a promise that is continually replenished. It would also allow the queue to fill up with out needing to worry about handling each result immediately.

Comment: I was hoping to get a Promise result so that everytime the task completed I could do something with it .

Comment: I suppose you could implement something like that with a BlockingQueue? Have the scheduled job put the results into the queue, and use `take()` to block until there's a result.